# "package installer keeps stopping"

Tags: apk, f-droid

I have a rooted (Magisk) Fairphone 5 running the Fairphone ROM.  I installed F-Droid using adb.  I cannot update F-Droid itself from with in F-Droid.  From F-Droid I have tried to install OI File Manager, LinPhone, and Easter Eggs.  They do not install and the only feedback I get is "package installer keeps stopping".  I also downloaded the [OI File Manager apk from the github site](https://github.com/openintents/filemanager/releases) directly to my phone and tried to install it from AOSP file manager with the same results. I am allowing installing APKs from unknown sources in settings.  I *am* able to install apks using `adb`.

I ran `adb logcat` when trying to install OI File Manager and found two possible errors:

```
NotificationService: Cannot find enqueued record for key: 0|org.fdroid.fdroid|1|https://f-droid.org/repo/org.openintents.filemanager_40.apk|10195
```

```
PackageParser: Unknown element under <manifest>: meta-data at /data/user/0/org.fdroid.fdroid/cache/apks/f-droid.org--1/org.openintents.filemanager_40.apk Binary XML file line #63
```

I have also installed [SAI](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.aefyr.sai.fdroid/) which gives more detailed error messages and it says "Can't install packages while in secure FRP"

But since it is happening with different APKs, I am not sure how to proceed to fix this.

Comment: I know that this issue stems from the triggering of FRP at some point in the rooting or setup process.  So the solution is to solve that problem so I have posted a [new question to that end](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/255941/bypass-remove-frp-on-rooted-fairphone-5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, this problem is a system level problem, not a problem with F-droid, the package installer or any individual APK file.  I have solved it using

```
adb shell settings put secure secure_frp_mode 0
```

and this solution persists across restarts, at least in my rooted context.