# bypass/remove FRP on rooted Fairphone 5

Tags: rooting, frp

I [rooted a new Fairphone 5 using Magisk](https://xdaforums.com/t/rooting-fp5.4634181/post-89111662).  After rooting I wanted to run the setup wizard again so I used

```
adb shell
su
pm enable com.google.android.setupwizard/com.google.android.setupwizard.SetupWizardActivity
exit
exit
adb shell settings put secure user_setup_complete 0
adb reboot
```

At some point in the rooting and setting up process I must have triggered FRP because now I cannot install APKs outside of the Play store because of FRP.  I get the error

```
Can't install packages while in secure FRP
```

I can still install APKs with `adb`.  I can temporarily fix the problem using

```
adb shell settings put secure secure_frp_mode 0
```

Otherwise I have full access to my phone and I have not had basic access to phone blocked by a "verify my google account" dialog like so many people having FRP issues.

There are quite a few discussions at [android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com) about dealign with FRP problems, some with answers.  Some of the answers seem device specific but none deal with Fairphone 5.  Is there a device-neutral way to fix this FRP issue?   I have moved data and apps over to this new phone from my old phone so I would prefer to not have to do a factory reset to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I said above that using

```
adb shell settings put secure secure_frp_mode 0
```

was a temporary fix but in fact it persists across restarts. So for this rooted phone, I am saying that this is the answer.